# Как узнать пустая ли функция?

Tags: python, python-3.x, метапрограммирование

Как узнать имеет функция или метод тело? То есть не просто

```
def f():
    pass
```

Comment: Уточните что вы пытаетесь сделать. Если анализ файла - то просто проверьте следующие строки.

Comment: В runtime узнать есть ли тело у функции или нет.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам это?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот более стабильный способ(`inspect.getsourcelines` далеко не всегда отрабатывает)

```
import dis


def check(function):
    instructions = dis.get_instructions(function)
    instr = next(instructions, None)
    if (instr is None) or (instr.opname != 'LOAD_CONST') or (instr.argrepr != 'None'):
        return False
    instr = next(instructions, None)
    return instr and (instr.opname == 'RETURN_VALUE')
```

Как это работает?
    У каждой функции есть атрибут `__code__` в котором записана байтовая строка опкодов. У пустой функции всего 2 опкода `LOAD_CONST(загрузить None в стек)` и `RETURN_VALUE(вернуть то что в стеке(то есть None))`. Мы соответственно и проверяем это.

Comment: А можно пояснить в ответе зачем нужны проверки?

Comment: @gil9red пояснил

Comment: байт-код это деталь реализации CPython. В зависимости от задачи, методы, основанные на исходном коде (inspect, ast) могут быть более переносимыми.

Answer (score 7):

Воспользоваться методом [inspect.getsourcelines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) и проанализировать содержимое функции:

```
def foo():
    pass

import inspect
lines = inspect.getsourcelines(foo)
print(lines)  # (['def foo():\n', '    pass\n'], 7)
print(lines[0][-1].strip() == 'pass')  # True
```

Answer (score 5):

Функция в Питоне всегда что-то делает, так как все функции в Питоне возвращают значение при успешном завершении, поэтому как минимум присутствует код, который возвращает `None`.

Примеры:

```
def f():
    pass

def f():
    ''

def f():
    return

def f():
    return None

f = lambda: None
```

*Все* эти функции имеют практически *идентичный* байт-код на моей версии СPython:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

<sup>(стоит упомянуть, что как наличие байт-кода так и как следствие конкретные результаты, генерируемые `dis` модулем — это детали реализации выбранной версии CPython. Сам по себе Питон не требует наличия байт-кода).</sup>

На уровне исходного кода так и на уровне AST эти функции отличаются:

```
>>> import ast
>>> def dump_ast(func_source): return ast.dump(ast.parse(func_source, 'exec').body[0])
... 
>>> dump_ast("def f(): pass")
"FunctionDef(name='f', args=arguments(args=[], vararg=None, kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=[Pass()], decorator_list=[], returns=None, docstring=None)"
>>> dump_ast("def f(): ''")
"FunctionDef(name='f', args=arguments(args=[], vararg=None, kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=[], decorator_list=[], returns=None, docstring='')"
```

<sup>(отличаются значения `body`, `docstring`).</sup>

Формально, тело функции пустое только во втором случае здесь.

*Что использовать для определения что такое "пустая функция": исходный код, [АСД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), байт-код — зависит от вашей задачи.*

Не все функции определены в чистом Питоне, к примеру, встроенные функции такие как `len()` могут быть на другом языке определены (Си, Java, RPython -- в  зависимости от реализации Питона):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(f)
False
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(len)
True
```

Или внешние функции:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
>>> libc.printf(b"abc\n")
abc
4
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(libc.printf)
False
```

Опять таки, считать такие функции "пустыми" или нет — зависит от задачи (разные варианты могут выгодны в разных ситуациях).